# .NET code generator command is executing the scaffold only when I stop the execution

Tags: c#, process, code-generation, scaffolding

I'm running the dotnet code generator commands from C# (using `Process` class), I'm able to create project using `dotnet new mvc` and I'm also able to add nuget packages. But I'm not able to scaffold when application is running. Scaffold happens only when I stop solution.

```
Process p = getProcess();
p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd C:\\Users");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("mkdir " + projName);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + projName);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet new sln");

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet new mvc -n " + projName);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet sln add .\\" + projName + ".\\" + projName + ".csproj");

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + projName);
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design -v 1.1.6");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design");

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet add package bootstrap");

string connString = "Server = " + serverAddr + "; Database = " + dbName + "; Trusted_Connection = True;";               
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold " + " 
            \"" + connString + "\" " + 
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models 
             --project " + projName);
```

Comment: What's this got to do with Powershell?

Comment: Try calling `p.StandardInput.Flush()` to ensure the lines are actually pushed to the process io

Comment: HI @MathiasR.Jessen I have tried p.StandardInput.Flush(), still it is not doing the scaffolding.

Comment: Hi @Sean it is not related to powershell, i am working on autocode generation from mvc using aspnet code-generator, i need to run all the commands like create project, install nuget, add scaffolded views etc..

Comment: @Mohammedathaullabaig - You've tagged the question as being Powershell related.